# python dataframe converts integer to float

Tags: python, dataframe

With my code, I combine multiple files to a dataframe and convert the NaN values to zero. In the code, I combine two columns (genome and contig) to a new column (source), but my dataframe converts somewhere the column contig from a integer to a float. My inputfile looks like this

```
AAA 1 345
AAB 2 344
```

The output is now like:

```
AAA_1.0 345
AAB_2.0 344
```

And I want to have it like

```
AAA_1 345
AAB_2 344
```

Since my code is very long, I can not place the whole code and all example files on this site, but the part of my code where this probably happend is as follows. I hope that this will be enough for someone to see what the problem is.

```
#import contig length
df5bb = pd.read_csv('count_contiglength.out', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["genome", "contig", "contig_length"])
df5bb['source'] = df5bb.genome.astype(str).str.cat(df5bb.contig.astype(str), sep='_')
df5bb = df5bb.set_index('source')
df5b = pd.merge(df5a, df5bb, how='outer')
df5b['source'] = df5b.genome.astype(str).str.cat(df5b.contig.astype(str), sep='_')

nan_cols = df5b.columns[df5b.isnull().any(axis=0)]
for col in nan_cols:
    df5b[col] = df5b[col].fillna(0).astype(int)

#import contigIDnumbers
df5cc = pd.read_csv('contigID.out', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["genome", "contig", "contigID"])
df5cc['source'] = df5cc.genome.astype(str).str.cat(df5cc.contig.astype(str), sep='_')
df5cc = df5cc.set_index('source')
df5c = pd.merge(df5b, df5cc, how='right')
df5c['source'] = df5c.genome.astype(str).str.cat(df5c.contig.astype(str), sep='_')
```

Comment: I have no data, but it seems you get `NaN`s after `merge`, so `int` is changed to `float`.

Comment: Try check it by `print (df5c[df5c.genome.isnull()])`

Comment: So you mean that if I merge the two dataframes, and when I get NaN, the dtype of the columns are changed to float?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only one `NaN` in column change `int` to `float`

Comment: Check [na type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions)

Comment: And is it possible to change that back? Will this work?  ' `df5c['genome'].astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, if there are no `NaN` use `df5b['genome'] = df5b['genome'].astype(int)`. But if `NaN` need `df5b['genome'] = df5b['genome'].fillna(0).astype(int)`.

Comment: Try first, if NaN it raise error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think after merge you get at least one `NaN` in column `genome`.

So need again:

```
df5b['genome'] = df5b['genome'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Check [na type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) - `int` are converted to `float`.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks for explaining and your help!